# nightmare.js not returning any output

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I try to run my test.js file below with the command:

```
 DEBUG=nightmare node --harmony test.js
```

and taking output:

```
 nightmare queueing action "goto" for http://google.com +0ms
 nightmare queueing action "wait" +2ms
 nightmare queueing action "screenshot" +0ms
```

test.js:

```
 var Nightmare = require('nightmare');

 var google = new Nightmare()
    .goto('http://google.com')
    .wait()
    .screenshot("./screen.png")
    .run(function(err, nightmare) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
            console.log('Done!');
    });
```

No screenshot and link access. Is there any idea?

note: i am working on Virtual Box with Linux Guest.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
var google = new Nightmare({ show: true })
```

You will be able to see if the link is opening or not.

For Debug try using the below instead:

```
DEBUG=nightmare:actions node --harmony test.js
```

This will show you that the code is throwing error like in your case:

```
nightmare:actions Not enough arguments for .wait()
```

.wait() requires either a time interval or a function returning true or a dom element.

Try something like:

```
.wait(2000) // For 2 sec wait
.wait("input[type='text'][title='Search']") // To wait till the search box is loaded
.wait( () => {
    // Check Something
    return true
})
```

Please check if the above helps is resolving your issue.

Comment: unfortunately, even though i applied those steps, still i see the same results. i have found a link ; discussing similar case [https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/142](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/142). I think there is a crucial problem with the phantomjs or other libraries?!. It does not matter how large number that i enter to the .wait() function, it passes with 0ms.

Comment: I tried your code snippet on my Linux and it worked perfectly fine. The only hiccup was the wait() section.

Anyways, hope it would have helped. Will try to dig deeper.

Comment: thanks aditya, i think i have problems with the versions of phantomjs or nodejs. i agree with you that your snippets should work as far as i have seen from the different examples on the web. I use Centos and is there any recommandation for nightmarejs installation that you apply.